# Enhanced content in Gradle Junit XML report - How to get properties and environment variables

Tags: gradle, junit

We have framework that splits tests to many machines. Data related to environment, OS etc are important for analysis of final result.

Gradle provides XML report compatible with existing tools.  Passed/Failed details, timing information, hostname etc are part of XML.   This however does not have some data such as environment variables or system properties used.  Another example is lack of  "OS" information in result.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_reporting covers many options.  I could not find a way to force more detailed test report.  Anyone managed to create more detailed XML?